# How to use background.html in manifest v3 in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to use the library of ffmpeg.wasm to download m3u8 videos in the background.js but it shows the error

```
ffmpeg.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: document is not defined
at ffmpeg.js:1
at ffmpeg.js:1
at f (ffmpeg.js:1)
at Generator._invoke (ffmpeg.js:1)
at Generator.next (ffmpeg.js:1)
at n (ffmpeg.js:1)
at c (ffmpeg.js:1)
at ffmpeg.js:1
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at ffmpeg.js:1
```

After I checked the document, it suggested me to use jsdom or create a new tab or window.

> Service workers do not have access to windows or the DOM. If your
> extension needs that, you can use libraries like jsdom or use
> chrome.windows.create and chrome.tabs.create. It depends on your usage
> and what fits your needs.
>
> This is also needed if your background scripts record audio or video,
> as that is not possible in service workers.

However, the document did not actually teach me how to do. I tried to use chrome.windows.create and chrome.tabs.create but it is not what I want because it actually create a new window or tab explicitly.

Then, I tried to use jsdom. I installed it with NPM. After I imported the library, it showed the error

```
service worker registration failed
```

Here is my manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "vDonwloader",
    "description": "Download HLS videos.",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
          "js": ["contentScript.js"],
          "run_at": "document_start"
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "webRequest",
        "tabs"
    ],
    "host_permissions":[
        "<all_urls>"
    ]
  }
```

Here is my background.js:

```
importScripts('ffmpeg.js');


const { createFFmpeg, fetchFile } = FFmpeg;

const downloadHlsListener = async (msg, sender, sendResponse) => {
    if(msg.action === 'DOWNLOAD_HLS'){
      //...Do something

    }
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(downloadHlsListener);
```

How can I solve this problem? I want to make a chrome extension to download .m3u8 videos with ffempeg library.

Comment: That quote does say how to do it: [`chrome.windows.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/windows/create) or [`chrome.tabs.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/create).

Comment: @Ouroborus these two methods will actually create a window or tab. Its not what I want.

Comment: Putting the quote, the error message, and the extension development documentation together: Load/run the library in the page, not the background. You'll of course need to move other parts of your code to the page as well.

Comment: @Ouroborus but in manifest v3, it allows to create background.html page.

Comment: I imagine that, aside from the stuff listed [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/mv3-migration-checklist/), v3 is the same as v2. So `"background": { "page": "background.html", "persistent": false },`. Note that v3 doesn't seem to support remote scripts so you'll need to bundle `ffmpeg.js`.

Comment: @Ouroborus I've tried "background": { "page": "background.html", "persistent": false }, it still show error msg.

Comment: The [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/) say "Background pages in MV2 are replaced by service workers in MV3: this is a foundational change that affects most extensions." Service workers don't have a DOM but, from the error message, ffmpeg.js requires a DOM. So your choices are any of: use v2; rewrite ffmpeg.js to remove the DOM dependency; or, do your work in the content page.

Comment: @MichaelTsai any update, did you fix this issue? Any workaround. could you pls share

Comment: @ankitd No any update and not fix. I finally give up the project